# Shrink Database

Tags: database, mysql, enterprise-1.13

I am looking at a Less than busy client on their database size

I get the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
| Tables                                        | Size in MB |
+-----------------------------------------------+------------+
| catalog_product_index_price_cl                |    3057.00 |
| cataloginventory_stock_status_cl              |    1974.00 |
| catalogsearch_fulltext_cl                     |     101.64 |
| catalog_product_flat_cl                       |     100.64 |
| catalog_category_product_index_cl             |      37.58 |
| sales_flat_order_item                         |      29.34 |
| catalog_product_index_price                   |      16.58 |
| customer_entity_varchar                       |      14.09 |
| catalog_product_index_price_idx               |      12.06 |
| catalog_product_entity_varchar                |      10.58 |
| index_event                                   |      10.03 |
| customer_entity_int                           |       6.61 |
| catalog_product_entity_decimal                |       6.55 |
| catalog_product_entity_int                    |       5.45 |
| catalog_product_entity_datetime               |       5.36 |
| catalogsearch_fulltext                        |       4.80 |
| region_city                                   |       4.52 |
```

Which I find kind of shocking. Why would the price index be 3gb? This is the dev database, can I safely shrink it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*_cl` tables are the changelog tables. They log all the IDs of products,stock, etc. which are changed.

A cronjob should theoretically update the indexes (async indexer) and then delete the entries from the table.

Comment: I checked the dev server and they have a cron running. Do you think this is an issue I should bring up to Magento?

Comment: We had the same problem. Because we have some deadlock or something which broke the cron and the table only get filled. So we downgraded to 1.12. What you can try is to delete the tables and check whether this problem doesn't come again. But this might outdate your index